# How to merge 3 Pandas Dataframes based on Timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have three dataframes in Pandas, say `df1, df2 and df3`. The first column of all dataframes is the Timestamp (DateTime format like `2017-01-01 12:30:00` etc.) Here is an example of each's first column:-

```
df1 TimeStamp
    2016-01-01 12:00:00 
    2016-01-01 12:10:00 
      .....
df2 TimeStamp
    2016-01-01 12:00:00 
    2016-01-01 12:10:00 
      .....
df3 TimeStamp
    2016-13-01 12:00:00 
    2016-13-01 12:30:00 
      .....
```

As you can see, for the first two are at 10 minutes intervals, while the third one is at 30 minutes intervals. What I would like to do is to merge all 3 dataframes together, such that for cases where there is not exact match due to non-available data(like `12:10:00` not available for 3rd dataframe ), it would be considered as `12:00:00` (the preceding measurement) for merging purposes. (But of course, the Date should be the same) Note that all the dataframes have different sizes, but I would like to merge them based on Timestamp together for analytical purposes. Thank you!

```
DESIRED RESULT:
df_final TimeStamp      ..  Columns of df1 Columns of df2 Columns of df3
    2016-13-01 12:00:00
    2016-13-01 12:10:00 
    2016-13-01 12:20:00 

      .....
```

**MORE DETAILS BASED ON ANSWER SUGGESTED**
Firstly, as my dataframes (all 3) did not have index as TimeStamps, but had columns as TimeStamps, I set index for each as the TimeStamps:

```
df1.index = df1.TimeStamp
df2.index = df2.TimeStamp
df3.index = df3.TimeStamp
```

On using this

```
u_index = df3.index.union(df2.index.union(df1.index))
```

I get a weird output strangely which is not at regularly 10 min intervals like needed.

```
Index(['2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000',
       '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000',
    ...
       '2017-12-31 23:50:00.000', '2017-12-31 23:50:00.000',
       '2017-12-31 23:50:00.000', '2017-12-31 23:50:00.000',

      dtype='object', name='TimeStamp', length=3199372)
```

Accordingly, the final df1_n dataframe is at `30 min` intervals and not `10 mins` (as the Union of indices was not properly done). I think that there is something going wrong here and once Step 2 suggested (`u_index`) is working properly, everything will be easy to merge the dataframes.

Comment: For the examples you gave, what is your desired result?

Comment: @wwii The desired result (added an edit) would be a dataframe at 10 minutes interval, wherein the date matches in all 3 of them, and for time, as df3 is at 30 min intervals, I would consider the measurements in between (say 12:10, 12:20 times as 12:00 as the records are not available). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not 100% sure if what you asked for is how to complete the missing values after merging the three dataframes with the next valid observation. 
if so, that's the quickest way I found to do this (not the most elegant...):

1. create a new index which is the union of the three indexes (will result in timestamp with intervals of 10 minutes in you case).
2. reindex all three dfs according to the new index while filling in missing values separately.
3. merge columns of the three dfs (which will be easy since after step NO.2 they will have the same index).

taking a portion of the data:

```
    df1
Out[48]: 
                     val_1
TimeStamp                 
2016-01-01 12:00:00     11
2016-01-01 12:10:00     12
df2
Out[49]: 
                     val_2
TimeStamp                 
2016-01-01 12:00:00     21
2016-01-01 12:10:00     22
df3
Out[50]: 
                     val_3
TimeStamp                 
2016-01-01 12:00:00     31
2016-13-01 12:30:00     32
```

step NO.1

```
u_index = df3.index.union(df2.index.union(df1.index))
u_index
Out[38]: Index(['2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:10:00', '2016-13-01 12:30:00'], dtype='object', name='TimeStamp')
```

step NO.2

```
df3_n = df3.reindex(index=u_index,method='bfill')
df2_n = df2.reindex(index=u_index,method='bfill')
df1_n = df1.reindex(index=u_index,method='bfill')
```

step NO.3

```
df1_n.merge(df2_n,on='TimeStamp').merge(df3_n,on='TimeStamp')
Out[47]: 
                     val_1  val_2  val_3
TimeStamp                               
2016-01-01 12:00:00   11.0   21.0     31
2016-01-01 12:10:00   12.0   22.0     32
2016-13-01 12:30:00    NaN    NaN     32
```

You might need to adjust the last row, since it has no following row to fill values from. but that's it pretty much.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, I am still getting the final dataframe (df1_n as you mention at 30 mins interval while I would like it at 10 mins interval). I am adding more details to my question based on your code. Would be great if you could tell what is going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: reasons I can think of why it did not work in your case: (1.) the index wasn't sorted - you can add a flag sort=True when you use index.union. (2.) elements are being repeated several times - you can try np.unique(u_index.values) and then convert it back to pandas index. The first think I would check is the number of overall elements in u_index, that should tell you which of the two suggestions will help. Let me now if it worked :)

Comment: thanks again! On using first suggestion, I can see that the u_index has length=3428255 which is exactly what I require, but strangely, the elements are widely repeated. Though df1 has elements at 10 minutes intervals and its length is 3428255, exactly what is needed, but resulting u_index does seem to have multiple repeats & comes to something like this Index(['2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000',
       '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000',...'2017-12-31 23:50:00.000', '2017-12-31 23:50:00.000'],
      dtype='object', name='TimeStamp', length=3428255), not like the TimeStamps in df1.

Comment: On using 2nd suggestion, u_index is in 10 minutes intervals, array(['2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-01-01 00:10:00.000',
       '2016-01-01 00:20:00.000', ..., '2017-12-31 23:30:00.000',
       '2017-12-31 23:40:00.000', '2017-12-31 23:50:00.000'], dtype=object)
but length is only 105264, far lower than 3428255.   Here is the original df shapes (I would like output to be df1 shape, and df1 is at 10 min intervals)                                    df1.shape: (3428255, 28)
df2.shape: (11362, 94)
df3.shape: (34576, 35)Thank you :-)

Comment: can you please tell why u_index has 3428255  overall elements, but not at 10 minutes intervals. In the original df1, these are at 10 minutes intervals and this thing is confusing me for days. Thank you once again

Comment: Hi! sorry for the delay. It's hard to say what is the exact problem when not seeing the code and the data but what I whould do is try to think of it as a simple union of 3 lists of strings and then converting back to pandas dataframe. You can use index.values for each df and then use np.union1d and np.unique

Comment: Thank you once again for your reply! Just checked out your idea and got 105264 elements. Then, on further checking, I realised that the problem is that these values are recorded for operation of different machines which have separate names say A1, A2, A3 etc. There is a column in df1 - "MachineName" to state which Machine these values were recorded for. So yes, the TimeStamp are being repeated, but this means we should not discard the repeated timestamp (as at same time interval, multiple machines can work together).

Comment: However, df2 and df3 have no column called MachineName- df2 and df3 are less regular measurements about the operating conditions of say, the environment in which the machines are kept. Thereby, df2 and df3 are in 30 minutes intervals, while df1 (operation status of machines) is in 10 minutes intervals. What I would like is a new dataframe (similar to df1, with same timestamps), but having columns from df2 and df3 together as well, so I can include them in my measurements. :)